# how to delay for loop iterations in swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, delayed-execution, timedelay

i have write the follwing code for my function but i failed to execute iterations after delaying.
I want iterations with delay, for example when loop completed execution till i =2 after this when i == 3 this should execute after some delay.
Please guide me to solve this problem.

```
func allCellsAttempted() -> Bool {

    var allCellsAttempted = true

    var count = 0
    if !oldVersionTriggered {
        count = micSources.count
    }
    else {
        count = olderVersionMicSources.count
    }

    print("Total Mics : \(count)")

    for i in 0..<count {


        if let cell = micTestFaliureTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? MicFaliureTableViewCell {

            if !cell.micFaliureTestview.attempted {
                allCellsAttempted = false
                break
            }

        }
    }

    return allCellsAttempted
}
```

Comment: Why not use a timer instead of a for loop?

Comment: i want to iterate in count..please tell me how to do with timer

Comment: Keep your count in a property. Each time the timer fires, process the next item and increment the count.  When you have reached the end, invalidate the timer.

Comment: please write the example using my code

Comment: where do you call your func `allCellsAttempted() -> Bool`

Comment: i am calling this func in another function like in allCellsSuccess()

Answer (score 1):

You could use a timer.  You will need to pass a completion handler closure to your function to access the result.

I would also suggest you access the information from the underlying data model rather than from the table view cells.

```
func allCellsAttempted(_ completion: @escaping(_ attempted: Bool)-> Void) -> Void {

    var allCellsAttempted = true

    var count = 0
    var target: Int

    if !oldVersionTriggered {
        target = micSources.count
    }
    else {
        target = olderVersionMicSources.count
    }

    print("Total Mics : \(target)")

    let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] (timer) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }
        if let cell = strongSelf.micTestFaliureTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: count, section: 0)) as? MicFaliureTableViewCell {
            if !cell.micFaliureTestview.attempted {
                allCellsAttempted = false
            }
        }
        count += 1
        if count == target || !allCellsAttempted {
            timer.invalidate()
            completion(allCellsAttempted)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now() + 2.0, execute: { })